# TextBox loses value after post back with TextMode Number

Tags: asp.net, textbox, updatepanel

Got weird problem. I have simple page with `TextBox`:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="amountTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Number" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Confirm" OnClick="confirmButton_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

After `Button` click I try to get `TextBox` value:

```
public partial class test : Page {
    protected void confirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var answer = amountTextBox.Text;
    }
}
```

but it's empty. If I remove `UpdatePanel`, I manage to get the value. If I leave `UpdatePanel` and remove `TextMode` property, I manage to get the value. But why can't I have `TextBoxt` with `TextMode` set to `Number` in `UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is [a known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651085/partial-postback-updatepanel-do-not-post-new-html5-input-fields-type-number), a fix is available  in .NET 4.5 RTM.

Description

> HTML5 has new types for the input tag, such as type="number", which is
>   needed to make mobile phones display a numerical keyboard instead of a
>   text keyboard. When doing a full postback of the page it works in all
>   browsers. But if I puts these in an updatepanel on a website to do a
>   partical postback, then none of the new HTML input types are included
>   in the postback response to the server from those browsers that
>   understands these new types (Safari/WebKit and Opera). It works
>   correctly in IE8 and Firefox 4, but probably only because they have
>   not implemented these new types and falls back to understanding it as
>   a type="text" field.

Here is another question with this issue and workarounds: [UpdatePanel with input type other than text in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649343/updatepanel-with-input-type-other-than-text-in-html5).