# Text on Textmode Time property in .NET 4.5 disappears in Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, html, textbox

I read many topics about this but I'm having a problem with the Textmode = "Time" property on .NET 4.5, as well.

I have this on aspx side:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxStartTime" TextMode="Time"></asp:TextBox>
```

On vb.net side, when I try to get the Text value from this textbox, I have nothing but empty string ("").

```
CDate(txtBoxStartTime.Text)
```

On client-side, in webInspector I can easily take the value from the textbox, but I need it in server-side...

Even though I try with HTML5 tags with runat="server" I encounter the same problem.

I've noticed the problem is the same with all of the Textmode Property on Framework 4.5

Any suggestions/solutions on this? 
I truly appreciate your input!

Thanks!

Comment: I found my solution to this problem in question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777011/textbox-loses-value-after-post-back-with-textmode-number

Answer (score 4):

Use this Attribute: "format"

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="server" TextMode="Time" format="HH:mm" />
```

it will return the format of 24 for hours.

if your value is 10:00 PM then in server side the (txtTime.Text) value will be "22:00".

I Test it in Chrome and it's work

Answer (score 2):

[TextBoxMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

> SingleLine mode displays the TextBox control as a single row. If the
>   user enters text that exceeds the physical size of the TextBox
>   control, the text will scroll horizontally. MultiLine mode displays
>   the height of the TextBox based on the Rows property, and allows data
>   entry on multiple lines. The text will automatically wrap if the Wrap
>   property is set to true. If the user enters text that exceeds the
>   physical size of the TextBox, the text will scroll accordingly and
>   scroll bars will appear. The behavior of Password mode is similar to
>   SingleLine mode except that all characters entered in the TextBox
>   control are masked and are not saved in view state.

and then

> The remaining options correspond to type attribute values for the
>   input element in the HTML5 specification.

So there is not any change to server side behaviours of textbox, the following code works as expected

**Markup**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Time" ID="test"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="ok" />
```

**C# code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string value = test.Text;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should be right... I don't know why this is happening to mine. I'm still investigating. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I surely can say on PostBack, the value disappears from the TextBox! Anyone know why? I put a validation on common textbox and if that fails the value from the "Time" textbox is removed...

Comment: In my case I was accidentally cleaning text on postback few lines before accessing Text Property.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `HH:mm` time format:

```
Time.Text = SomeTime.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing this in your page_load?

```
txtBoxStartTime.Attributes["type"] = "Time"
```

Comment: I've tried txtBoxStartTime.Attributes("value") and it is "Nothing". I'm trying your suggestion right now to see.

Answer (score 0):

So, to have an answer, here's the code it's on my Page.Load (for testing)

[image]
 You can see there's not value on txtBoxStarTime.Text

[image]

For my situation, I have this inside an update panel:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxStartTime" TextMode="Time" Width="102px"></asp:TextBox>


<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxEndTime" TextMode="Time" Width="102px"></asp:TextBox>


<asp:Button CssClass="positive" ID="btnOtherSendRequest" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;Send Request" ToolTip="The selected request would be sent to X" OnClick="btnOtherSendRequest_Click"/>
```

This is the code in VB.NET:

```
Protected Sub btnOtherSendRequest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try

        lblSubmitted.Text = ""
        lblValidateNotInfo.Text = ""
        hdnRequestType.Value = "OTH"

        Dim messageSuccessful As String = "Thank you for submitting your Request(s)!"
        Dim messageUnSuccessful As String = "The Request was not submitted due to some errors. Please 'Go Back' and re-send!"

        Select Case ddlRequest.SelectedValue
            Case "18" ' Schedule Update Call
                If Not (txtBoxStartDate.Text.Length > 0 And txtBoxEndDate.Text.Length > 0 And IsDate(txtBoxStartDate.Text) And IsDate(txtBoxEndDate.Text)) Then
                    ' AI - if dates are in invalid format
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "AlertScript", "alert ('Please make sure the dates are in a valid format!');", True)
                    Exit Sub
                ElseIf Not CDate(txtBoxStartDate.Text).CompareTo(Date.Now) > 0 Then
                    ' AI - Start Date must be greater than today.
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "AlertScript", "alert ('""Start"" date must be a future date!');", True)
                    Exit Sub
                ElseIf Not CDate(txtBoxEndDate.Text).CompareTo(CDate(txtBoxStartDate.Text)) >= 0 Then
                    ' AI - Start Date must be greater than today.
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "AlertScript", "alert ('""End"" date must be the same as the ""Start"" date or a date after the ""Start"" date!');", True)
                    Exit Sub
                ElseIf CDate(txtBoxStartDate.Text).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or CDate(txtBoxStartDate.Text).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Or CDate(txtBoxEndDate.Text).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or CDate(txtBoxEndDate.Text).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "AlertScript", "alert ('Weekends excluded!');", True)
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    lblSubmitted.Text = messageSuccessful
                End If
            Case "19" ' Request Training Call
            Case "20" ' Request Call from Cust. Service
            Case "21" ' Other Request
                If txtBoxOther.Text <> "" Then
                    lblSubmitted.Text = messageSuccessful
                Else
                    lblSubmitted.Text = messageUnSuccessful
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "AlertScript", "alert ('Please enter your request into the textarea first!');", True)
                    txtBoxOther.Focus()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
        End Select

        Call sendRequest()


        Call JSEffect(True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMessage.Text = "Error when taking the request to be inserted - " & ex.Message
    Finally
        hlServCenterPend.Text = "Pending Requests (" & getServCenterStatus("PEND").ToString & ")"
        hlServCenterComp.Text = "Completed Requests (" & getServCenterStatus("COMP").ToString & ")"
    End Try
End Sub
```

And Here I got the error:

```
Public Sub sendRequest(Optional pid As Integer = 0, Optional claim As Integer = 0, Optional insured As Integer = 0)

    Dim req As New cls_services.request
    Try

        req.clinicID = CInt(MyMod.FetchStoredData("ClinicID"))
        req.pid = pid
        req.type = CInt(ddlRequest.SelectedValue)
        Select Case req.type
            Case 1, 11, 12, 13, 14
                req.status = "COMP"
            Case Else
                req.status = "PEND"
        End Select
        req.claimID = claim
        req.insuranceID = insured
        req.dueDate = req.getDueDate(req.type)
        req.other = Trim(txtBoxOther.Text)
        Select Case req.type
            Case 18
                req.fromDate = CDate(txtBoxStartDate.Text)
                req.fromTime = CDate(txtBoxStartTime.Text)//ERROR HERE! - EXCEPTION
                req.toDate = CDate(txtBoxEndDate.Text)
                req.toTime = CDate(txtBoxEndTime.Text)
        End Select
        req.fax = Trim(txtFaxTreatmentRecords.Text)
        req.createUser = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
```

My solution here, is trying to store the value from textbox in a hiddenfield, then access in codebehind... but it is still a "last-measure" solution.

The fact is, as I said - On PostBack - the "Text" value disappears. Don't know why.

Still waiting for suggestions! :)

Answer (score 0):

So,

I've been struggling with this for some hours. I did not find any "code-behind" solution. So I come with a solution. Maybe it will help you in some ways:

Using JavaScript to store the value into a hiddenfield, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxStartTime" TextMode="Time" Width="102px" onchange="storeStartTime()"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnStartTime"/>
```

JavaScript Function:

```
function storeStartTime() {
var x = document.getElementById("ctl00_mainPageBody_txtBoxStartTime");
var y = document.getElementById("ctl00_mainPageBody_hdnStartTime");
y.value = x.value;
alert(y.value);
```

}

Hope it will help if you encounter this problem!